# Translation surfaces

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology

I know that this definitely have some sort of reference out there, but I did not find any wikipidea page for it or any introductory Mathematical article about it . I just want definition and concrete examples of translation surfaces. For example, if I take four copies of equilateral triangle and glue them together side by side to form a tetrahedron, how do I put a Riemann surface structure on it ? I want some detailed explanations etc. Could you cite any reference(s) ?

Answer (score 7):

There is a huge literature, and I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for.  That being said, Masur-Tabachnikov's survey "Rational billiards and flat structures" and Masur's survey "Ergodic Theory of Translation surfaces" contain a lot of introductory material.  Both can be found on Masur's webpage [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~masur/papers.html).

Comment: Check this thread, it is amusing and you are involved:
$$ $$
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/802/a-reputation-table-bug/
$$ $$  

Answer (score 7):

People normally take the definition: translation surface = pair (X,w), where X is Riemann Surface and w is a non identically zero holomorphic form on X. Strictly, if you want to make a translation surface out of this pair you have to remove the zeros of w from X and then integrate w.

As a general reference take the book:

[Flat surfaces (by Anton Zorich)](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/anton.zorich/papers_e.html)

in collection "Frontiers in Number Theory, Physics and Geometry. Volume 1:
On random matrices, zeta functions and dynamical systems'',
P. Cartier; B. Julia; P. Moussa; P. Vanhove (Editors),
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 2006, 439-586.

Comment: Another introductory text is Yoccoz' notes: http://www.college-de-france.fr/media/jean-christophe-yoccoz/UPL15305_PisaLecturesJCY2007.pdf